# Git: after merge master with version-3.0 successfully master still didn't get all the updates

Tags: git

I have `master` and one branch called `version-3.0` after making changes on `version-3.0` and merge it with `master` I undo the merge and made other changes and then I merge it again.

after the second merge successfully done I found that the `master` still different and didn't get the updates from `version-3.0` branch.

try to merge again says 'already up to date'.

Comment: Reverts are commits which undo changes as a new commit. If you just want to undo it as if it never happened use reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I undo the merge and made other changes and then I merge it again.

If you've undone a merge by reverting the changes, the only way¹ to get the changes back is reverting that revert.

This is because the reverted version is a new version, not related to the original changes in any formal way, that is more recent in the history than the preceding merge and therefore takes priority.

I recommend you take some time to understand how the three-way merge algorithm works and how the most recent common ancestor gets selected. It is quite obvious once you do, but not easy to describe in a short post. You can ask git to show you the merge base by asking `git merge-base master version-3.0` (or any other pair of revisions) and you can visualise the list of changes on either side using `gitk master..version-3.0` (‘theirs’ side when merging from version-3.0 to master) and `gitk version-3.0..master` (‘ours’ side)—or again with any other two revision.

---

¹  Well, you can rebase on a version before the undesired merge and merge again on that, but that is a more advanced approach, and not really appropriate for `master` that has a lot of other branches based on it.